# Is there a way to make a video with python?

Tags: python, video, encoding

I have python 2.5 on a Windows XP computer. I want to create a video (preferably a AVI) from a list of images. I would also like to be able to add sound to the video. I have tried modules like pymedia (keeps crashing), pyFFMPEG (gived DLL NOT FOUND ImportError), pyglet (only displays videos), and OpenCV (would not install). I am want to compile my program into a windows executable with py2exe and I would be willing to use an external program if that program could be redistributed through my program and it could be Popened when the program is compiled. It would be nice if the program was compatible with PIL or pygame images, but if not I could probably work around that. If there is one out there like this, or if you can help me get PyFFMPEG to work with python 2.5, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should try to make the video using one of these modules first?

Comment: I have had success creating videos in Python by calling [`ffmpeg`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) using [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% clear on what you mean by 'make a video'.  You can run use mencoder if say you do not like using ffmpeg for some reason.

Whatever that may be, you need a video source and video encoder to generate a video.  Of course you could write your own video encoder in python if you wanted but that would leave you doing only that for next few months and it would run very slowly.

You need a raw YUV input to encode or another stream to transcode and 'make a video'.  The input can come from a hardware or a file or stream on a socket.